# MYSQL INSERT, UPDATE DELETE

Tags: mysql, replace, insert

I have two MYSQL tables `cases` and `pivot`

`cases` looks like this :

```
Idgame  Id
   1     2
   1     1
   1     5
   1     3
   1     1
   1     6
  ...   ...
   1     2
```

`pivot` looks like this :

```
Idgame   Id   Icone
   1      1      7
   1      2     14
   1      3     15
   1      5      6
   1      6      1
```

All Id in `pivot` must be the distinct Id of `cases`

Users can modify the Id in `cases`, so when there is a change I want to update `pivot`.

1) If there is a new Id not yet IN `pivot` I want to add a new line in `pivot` with Icone = 1 (I set 1 as the default value)

2) If some Id are no longer in `cases` I want to delete them in `pivot`

3) I don't change anything in `pivot` if the Id is still in `cases`

I'm trying to do that with REPLACE INTO or INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY but i can't manage to do it...

I tried something like below. It almost work but it doesn't perform deletion (point 2):
I added PRIMARY KEY on the 3 columns (id, idgame, and icone) in `pivot`.

```
REPLACE INTO `pivot` (id,idgame,icone)
SELECT DISTINCT cases.id, cases.idgame, pivot.icone
FROM `cases`
LEFT JOIN pivot ON (pivot.Idgame = cases.Idgame AND pivot.id = cases.id)
WHERE cases.Idgame = 1
```

Is it possible to do it with only one request ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do all these in one request. You have to use `MySQL Triggers` and `Stored Procedure`.

You can write triggers for `cases` table for `after delete` and `after insert` and `after update` events.

For more details please refer : 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-triggers.aspx